# Conditional php_flag statements in .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

Is there a way to conditionally execute php_flag statements in .htaccess? Here are two things I'm trying to do:

Turn error reporting on if the client's IP address matches the IP address I use:

```
if %{REMOTE_ADDR} == '12.34.56.78' then
   php_flag error_reporting 1
else
   php_flag error_reporting 0
```

Turn off `register_globals` if the IP address matches mine, so that I can debug any issues caused by the code expecting this turned on.

```
if %{REMOTE_ADDR} == '12.34.56.78' then
   php_flag register_globals on
else
   php_flag register_globals on
```

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> if %{REMOTE_ADDR} == '12.34.56.78' then
>    php_flag error_reporting 1
> else
>    php_flag error_reporting 0
> ```

This is only really possible with the advent of [Apache Expressions](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/expr.html) in Apache 2.4+, where you can do just this sort of thing...

```
<If "%{REMOTE_ADDR} == '12.34.56.78'">
    php_flag error_reporting 1
</If>
<Else>
    php_flag error_reporting 0
</Else>
```

If on Apache 2.2 this is not really possible, especially with something that is dependent on the request, like the `REMOTE_ADDR`. On Apache 2.2 you have `<IfDefine>`, but this only tests the existence of *parameters* that have been defined on the Appache command line with the `-D` option. So, this is really a per-server configuration switch. (On Apache 2.4 you can use the `Define` directive in the server config to *define* parameters somewhat conditionally, however, this still can't be defined based on elements of the request AFAIK. Besides, you have the use of Apache Expressions on Apache 2.4 anyway.)